# how to do i map through this object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

[image: array of objects]

it tried using like this

```
 { options.map( opt => {
          return <Text>{opt.value}</Text>
   }) }
```

Here iam taking the data from the backend and iam passing in to the DetailScreen.

```
class Poll extends Component {

  state = {
    loading:true,
    pollDetails : []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://192.168.43.22:5000/api/v1/questions/5f1c31e1089847468cb9c508')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => this.setState({pollDetails:responseJson.data}));
    this.setState({loading:false});
  }
  

  render() {

    const {loading, pollDetails} = this.state;
    
    if(loading){
      <View>
        <Text><ActivityIndicator/></Text>
      </View>
    }

    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <DetailsScreen 
        key={pollDetails._id}
        title={pollDetails.title}
        options={pollDetails.options}
        voteCount={pollDetails.voteCount}
        opinionCount={pollDetails.opinionCount}
        loaded={true}
        votes={60}
        />
      </ScrollView>);    
    }
  }
```

In Here i try to map through the options but it throws the error!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import Card from '../UI/Card';

export default class DetailScreen extends Component{

    state = {
        width:0,
        voteCount: this.props.voteCount
    }
    
    handleOnLayout = ( {nativeEvent} ) => {
        this.setState({width:nativeEvent.layout.width})
    }
    
    handleVotes = (id) => {
        console.log(this.state.voteCount)
     }
    
    render(){
        const {title, voteCount, votes, opinionCount, loaded} = this.props;


        const _animatedWidth = new Animated.Value(0);
    
        const animatedAnswerValue = () => {     
            const percentage = votes / voteCount;
            const rowWidth = Math.floor(this.state.width * percentage);
            
            Animated.timing(_animatedWidth,{
                toValue:rowWidth,
                duration:1500
            }).start();
        }
        animatedAnswerValue();
        
        const getOverlayStyles = (votes) => {
            const s = [styles.optionBar];
        
            if(votes > 50){
                s.push(styles.optionBarHigh);
            }
            if(votes < 50 && votes > 20){
                s.push(styles.optionBarMedium);
            }
            if(votes <= 20){
                s.push(styles.optionBarLow)
            }
            return s;
        }

        return(
            <View style={{marginLeft:100}}>
                <Text style={{marginTop:50}}>{title}</Text>
                {
                    this.props.options.map((opt,index) => {
                    return <Text key={index}>{opt.votes}</Text>
                    })
                }
                <Text>Just some sample text here!!!</Text>
                    {/* <TouchableOpacity key={options._id[0]} onPress={() => this.handleVotes(options._id)}>
                    <Card>
                        <Text>{options.value}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.optionBarRow} onLayout={this.handleOnLayout}>
                        <Animated.View 
                        style={[getOverlayStyles(this.props.votes,loaded), {width:_animatedWidth}]}/>
                        <View style={styles.opinions}>
                            <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Opinions</Text>
                        </View>
                        </View>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

but it throw error of "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

ive been scratching my head lately..
i'll be glad if some one sort this out for me!
thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you arrive at `options`? Post a complete code

Comment: First question, how are you making `options` available to this component ?

Comment: This error means that it thinks `options` doesn't exist. So wherever you're calling that code, make sure that you're grabbing options correctly. Are you sure it doesn't need to be `data.options` ?

Comment: i've updated my question look into it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might that data haven't been loaded on the very first render.
You can try to add an extra check for option to be in place, like:

```js
{ options && options.map( opt => {
          return <Text>{opt.value}</Text>
}) }
```

Comment: woww.. it did the magic!! btw look at  my code is it neccessary to add like this?

Comment: As an option you can pass options as an empty array on the Poll component level. Also, setState is async operation so you might avoid race conditions if you’d combine such. (When handle the server response)